# Half of the records are getting scraped out of 84

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I've made a parser in VBA which is able to scrape the name from yellow page Canada. However, the issue is that the page contains 84 Names but my parser is scraping only 41 Names. How can I fix this? Any help would be my blessing. Thanks in advance. Here is the code:

```
http.Open "GET", "http://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/Outdoor%20wedding/Edmonton", False
http.send
html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText

Set topics = html.getElementsByClassName("listing__name--link jsListingName")
For Each topic In topics
    Cells(x, 1) = topic.innerText
    x = x + 1
Next topic
```

Btw, I used the MSxml2.xmlhttp60 request.

Comment: What is the count for 'Topics'?

Comment: because the page is using lazy load. when you query the URL, actually 40 names are loaded. When you scroll down, rest of the names are loaded.

Comment: Thanks sir cyboashu, you are absolutely right. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Thanks sir Wayne, for your sharp response. I'm not that advanced in html element thing. Generally I count "topics" as a collection of htmlelement.

Comment: I think @WayneG.Dunn was simply asking about `topics.Count`, which you can find out with the debugger.

Comment: It's my bad that I couldn't get the question first. Anyways, topics.count gives me "run time error 438" but topics.length gives 40 as result.

Comment: You can try Power Query if your version of Excel supports it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the page's web requests, you'll notice it'll trigger another web request once the page has been scrolled past a certain point.

The format of the new requests is like this:

**First 40 records:** `http://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/Outdoor%20wedding/Edmonton`

**Next 40 records:** `http://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/2/Outdoor%20wedding/Edmonton`

**Next 40 records:** `http://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/3/Outdoor%20wedding/Edmonton`

Basically for new data (in batches of 40 records) it increments part of the URL by 1.

Which is good news, we can just do a loop to return the results. Here's the code I came up with. For whatever reason, the `getElementsByClassName` selector wasn't working for me, so I worked around it in my code. If you can use that selector, use that instead of what I have below for that part.

Lastly, I added an explicit reference to `Microsoft XML v6.0`, so you should do the same to get this to function as it is.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SOTestScraper()
    Dim topics      As Object
    Dim topic       As Object
    Dim webResp     As Object
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim j           As Long
    Dim mySheet     As Worksheet: Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change this
    Dim myArr()     As Variant: ReDim myArr(10000) 'Probably overkill

    For i = 1 To 20 ' unsure how many records you expect, I defaulted to 20 pages, or 800 results
        Set webResp = getWebResponse(CStr(i)) ' return the web response
        Set topics = webResp.getElementsByTagName("*") ' I couldn't find the className so I did this instead
        If topics Is Nothing Then Exit For 'Exit the for loop if Status 200 wasn't received
        For Each topic In topics
            On Error Resume Next
            'If getElementByClassName is working for you, use it
            If topic.ClassName = "listing__name--link jsListingName" Then
                myArr(j) = topic.InnerText
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'add the data to Excel
    ReDim Preserve myArr(j - 1)
    mySheet.Range("A1:A" & j) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myArr)
End Sub

Function getWebResponse(ByVal pageNumber As String) As Object
    Dim http As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60: Set http = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    Dim html As Object: Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")

    With http
        .Open "GET", "http://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/" & pageNumber & "/Outdoor%20wedding/Edmonton"
        .send
        .waitForResponse
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        .waitForResponse
    End With

    If Not http.Status = 200 Then
        Set getWebResponse = Nothing
    Else
        Set getWebResponse = html
    End If

    Set html = Nothing
    Set http = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Hi dear Ryan Wildry, thanks for your fruitful effort. Your answer on my any questions has always been a great help to me.